# Display date values as column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is my code to display date values as column name. 
But it won't get the new data of the next month unless encoded in Pivot values.
How should I do it dynamically?

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT REGION, STATUS, CAST((MONTH(TRANS_DATE))AS VARCHAR)+'-'+CAST(YEAR(TRANS_DATE)AS VARCHAR) AS TMONTH
FROM SOM_SAMPLE_MOVEMENT SM WHERE REGION IS NOT NULL AND TRANS_DATE IS NOT NULL AND STATUS='RECEIVED'

) T
PIVOT
(
COUNT(STATUS)
FOR TMONTH
IN ([11-2019],[12-2019],[1-2020],[2-2020],[3-2020])
)AS PVT
```

Below is the sample output.

```
REGION  11-2019 12-2019 1-2020  2-2020  3-2020
CEBU       3      10      15      0       0
```

Comment: did you already try to use "real" dynamic SQL? You can read your `CAST((MONTH(TRANS_DATE))AS VARCHAR)+'-'+CAST(YEAR(TRANS_DATE)AS VARCHAR)` into a concatenated and comma separated string, build your query using this string and execute this statement... I can provide an example if required.

Comment: an example would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use "real" dynamic SQL: First get your list of months and store it into a nvarchar variable using XML path. Then store your pivot query into a new variable, using the built month string and execute it.
See Fiddle for details:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/77538/21)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(
  REGION nvarchar(10), STATUS nvarchar(10), TRANS_DATE datetime
 );
```

**Query 1**:

```
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES
('CEBU', 'Received', '2019-12-01'),
('CEBU', 'Received', '2019-12-01'),
('CEBU', 'Received', '2019-12-01'),
('CEBU', 'Received', '2020-01-01'),
('CEBU', 'Received', '2020-01-01'),
('CEBU', 'Received', '2020-01-02'),
('CEBU', 'Received', '2020-02-01'),
('CEBU', 'Received', '2020-03-01'),
('CEBU', 'Received', '2020-03-01'),
('CEBU', 'Received', '2020-05-01'),
('CEBU', 'Received', '2020-06-01')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/77538/21/0)**:

**Query 2**:

```
DECLARE @MonthList NVARCHAR(max) =(
SELECT  STUFF(( SELECT  ', ' + '['+TMONTH+']'
                FROM    ( SELECT DISTINCT CAST((MONTH(TRANS_DATE))AS VARCHAR)+'-'+CAST(YEAR(TRANS_DATE)AS VARCHAR) AS TMONTH
  FROM T1
                        ) x
              FOR
                XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 2, '') AllMonth
)

DECLARE @Stmt NVARCHAR(max) = 'SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT REGION, STATUS, CAST((MONTH(TRANS_DATE))AS VARCHAR)+'+char(39)+'-'+char(39)+'+CAST(YEAR(TRANS_DATE)AS VARCHAR) AS TMONTH
FROM T1 SM WHERE REGION IS NOT NULL AND TRANS_DATE IS NOT NULL AND STATUS='+char(39)+'RECEIVED'+char(39)+'

) T
PIVOT
(
COUNT(STATUS)
FOR TMONTH
IN ('+@MonthList+')
)AS PVT'

EXEC(@stmt)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/77538/21/1)**:

```
| REGION | 1-2020 | 12-2019 | 2-2020 | 3-2020 | 5-2020 | 6-2020 |
|--------|--------|---------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|   CEBU |      3 |       3 |      1 |      2 |      1 |      1 |
```

Comment: @xXx thanks for editing - somehow forgot to paste the fiddle code here as well